# how to fetch same chat-id which is common in 2 rows who's id i know before

Tags: mysql, sql

i want the query to fetch the chat-id between 2 users I already have both of there user-id but don't know how to do that. there are a lot of chat-id's stored with every user-id but i only need to fetch 2 records which have the same chat-id and 2 different user-id which i will be providing the query.Thanks for reading and helping....

```
+-------+-------+
|chat-id|user-id|
+-------+-------+
|1      |1      |
+-------+-------+
|1      |2      |
+-------+-------+
|2      |1      |
+-------+-------+
|2      |3      |
+-------+-------+
|3      |2      |
+-------+-------+
|3      |3      |
+-------+-------+
|4      |1      |
+-------+-------+
|4      |4      |
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Provide sample data.

Comment: What query have you tried? Please paste it into the question as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want chats between two particular users:

```
select chat_id
from t
where user_id in (@id1, @id2)
group by chat_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

This assumes that the table does not have duplicates.  If it can, then use `count(distinct user_id) = 2`.

Comment: thank you sir i think this might be what i m looking for. i will try it in my code and see if it works the way i want it....thanks a lot